# Google Analytics Mobile SDK "request for permission" requirement

Tags: google-analytics, phonegap-plugins

The Google Analytics Plugin for PhoneGap has an example app that contains the following code:

```
// Note: A request for permission is REQUIRED by google. You probably want to do this just once, though, and remember the answer for subsequent runs.
navigator.notification.confirm('GA_PLUGIN would like your permission to collect usage data. No personal or user identifiable data will be collected.', permissionCallback, 'Attention', 'Allow,Deny');
```

I've looked through the Google Analytics mobile SDK docs (although I have not read them start-to-finish) and have been unable to locate this requirement. I also don't see it in the Terms of Service at http://www.google.com/analytics/terms/us.html.

I don't mind requesting permission from the end user, but I certainly don't do it on web sites and I don't seem to recall getting many of these requests within apps that I've installed either.

Is the comment in the code correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! Sort of. It's in the [Measurement Protocol / SDK Policy](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/policy) doc. It states:

> You will give your end users proper notice about the implementations and features of Google Analytics you use (e.g. notice about what data you will collect via Google Analytics, and whether this data can be connected to other data you have about the end user). You will either get consent from your end users, or provide them with the opportunity to opt-out from the implementations and features you use.

That's the Measurement Protocol / SDK Policy. It's not 100% clear to me that it refers to the iOS and Android SDKs. On the one hand, the table of contents type thing on the left has it under Measurement Protocol > Resources. The iOS and Android SDKs are outside of Measurement Protocol. So that suggests it doesn't apply to the iOS and Android SDKs. On the other hand, the Measurement Protocol doesn't seem to have an SDK associated with it, so that the suggests that "SDK" in the title may be referring to the iOS and Android SDKs.

I do wish this were clearer.